# Top level navigation from html link in code in Markup slice

Tags: slice, markup, apache-superset

I had seen a comments that Apache Superset was edited to allow user activation of top level navigation for links in a Markup slice (so clicking a link redirects the page instead of just the contents of the slice). Does anyone know how to enable this option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML coding in the mark-up.

```
<a href="http://www.url.com">It works</a>
```

Comment: This only redirects inside the slice itself, it doesn't do top level navigation (redirect the full page), so if you use that for navigation (linking to a "top level" dashboard") it will end up just nesting pages in pages. There is some configuration option to allow top level navigation but I don't know where to enable this

Comment: I use the HTML a href within my markup and it does not nest inside of the page, it opens the dashboard. Test it out by using target="_blank" I will take screenshots in the morning of my superset using the HTML href links.

Comment: It opens it in that slice but if you add the slice to a dashboard, the link only changes the content of that slice. I am looking for it to redirect the whole dashboard page - or are you saying that's what the link does for you?

Comment: In order to create a link and not redirect within the slice add target="_blank" inside the href coding

Comment: Adding target="_blank" works for the top-level navigation but it then opens the link in a new tab instead of just loading the new link in the current page/tab